# Android: Using Parcel to Generate a Deep Copy

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, deep-copy

I was told that it is possible to create a deep copy of an object by writing the object to a parcel, then immediately reading it out again.

So far, I have tried creating a Parcel and writing the object of interest to it as such:

```
Parcel.obtain().apply {
            setDataPosition(0)
            writeValue(searchRequestParams)
        }
```

Given that this is the correct way to write an object to a parcel, how can I read out the written object (to complete the deep copy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reset the data position back to zero and then call the reader method. Don't forget to recycle the `Parcel` object when done.

Generically you could provide an extension like this:

```
inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> T.deepCopy(): T {
  val parcel = Parcel.obtain().apply {
    writeParcelable(this@deepCopy, /* parcelableFlags= */ 0)
    setDataPosition(0)
  }
  
  val result = checkNotNull(parcel.readParcelable<T>(T::class.java.classLoader))
  parcel.recycle()
  return result
}
```

Then just use `myObject.deepCopy()` on any `Parcelable` type.